# CSS Separator on collated columns

Tags: css

I have 2 columns, floated one to each side, and I'd like to use a 1px width line separator, that goes from top to bottom of the longest column.

Id rather stay away of TABLE layouts, and I dont know which one will be the longest column, or how long will it be.

How could I do this with just css?

http://jsfiddle.net/AhfXc/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
.colright{ 
    float: right;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    left: -1px;
    position:relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AhfXc/18/

Answer (score 0):

You could fake it by putting a parent `div` around both and giving the parent a background image which would be a 200px wide, 1px high image with the a 1px black/gray dot in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with CSS.  Here's my version of your example: http://jsfiddle.net/AhfXc/15/

Basically, just make the separator be absolutely positioned within the parent container (make the parent position relative so this works).  Then attach the child to the top and bottom with top: 0 and bottom: 0.  You could set the separator background to be the colour you want, but I've used a border style since you could easily apply dashed/dotted style if you want to.

This does only works if the columns have a known absolute or relative width because the separator's horizontal position is not directly affected by them, but if this is the case, it's a fairly simple solution.